# How to create a HTTPS Proxy Server on Debian

Tags: linux, https, proxy, debian

I want to create a secure HTTPS proxy (not http) server on Debian. I tried squid but for some reason it doesn't work and there isn't any complete guides for it on the internet.

Can anyone suggest another program which is easy to work with, or provide a guide of achieving this with squid?

Answer (score 0):

`https` involves encryption of the data using an asymmetric (private/public) key that identifies the webpage, based on it's hostname.

therefore, you cannot build a *transparent* https-proxy - unless you have the private keys for all the `https://` servers out there (or at least those you want to access through the proxy), which is highly unlikely.

if you do have those keys (e.g. because you only want to provide https:// access to an ordinary http:// server that lives somewhere behind a firewall), check out the `mod_proxy` module for apache.